# How to send several emails in a single connection of IdSMTP?

Tags: ssl, smtp, indy

I am using Indy 10 on C++Builder 6.0 Professional Edition.

My SMTP server imposes a limit on the number of connections in a certain time interval, so I need to send more than one email using the same connection. Is it possible? How can I do that ?

I am already able to connect and send one email on each connection.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `TIdSMTP.Send()` multiple times between a single pair of `Connect()`/`Disconnect()` calls, adjusting the `TIdMessage` as needed for each `Send()` call.

```
IdSMTP1.Connect;
try
  // prepare TIdMessage as needed...
  IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);

  // prepare TIdMessage as needed...
  IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);

  // prepare TIdMessage as needed...
  IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
finally
  IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
end;
```

Comment: Can I use a new TIdMessage for each email ? I'd like to prepare all emails before sending them. Thank you very much for answering me.

Comment: @JaymeJeffman yes, you can use a new `TIdMessage` each time. Or, you can simply `Clear()` a single `TIdMessage` each time, too.